# Do we have to sort before aggregate?

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset like this:

```
x1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C")  
x2 = c(1,1,1,1)  
y = data.frame(cbind(x1,x2))
```

I want to calculate the sum of the column `x2` for each group in column `x1` using aggregate() function.

I wonder if I have to sort the dataframe by the column `x1` in ascending order first to be able to use `aggregate()` function or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is not necessary:

BTW: Don't use `cbind` as it converts all columns to one datatype, in your case to a `character`. Simply use `data.frame(x1, x2)`.

```r
x1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C")
x2 = c(1,1,1,1)
y = data.frame(x1, x2)

aggregate(x2 ~ x1, FUN = sum, data = y)
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  A  2
#> 2  B  1
#> 3  C  1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So, the aggregate() function will automatically sort the return dataframe by the "by" column right ?

Comment: Actually I don't use aggregate that often. But after quick check I would say: yes. (:

Comment: Hi, it means that you prefer another function other than "aggregate" to do the aggregation right ? Could you tell me which is that function ?

Comment: I wouldn't say prefer. But most of the time I make use of the `tidyverse`, i.e. using `group_by() + summarise()` from `dplyr`. But that's a matter of taste.